# What does this conversation about ghosts mean?

Tags: dialogue, interstellar

In *Interstellar* Cooper and his duaghter have the following conversation:

> **Murph:** Grandpa says you can get ghosts Dad.
>   **Cooper:** Maybe grandpa's a little too close to being one himself.

What is this about and what's the meaning of "get" and "a little too close to being one" in these phrases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Get" here means to have ghosts around you, or inhabiting your house. A more common phrase that uses it the same way is "if you keep food lying out you might get bugs in your house".

"Too close to being one himself" is a joking way of saying that he's old, and thus is soon to be a ghost himself (when he dies of old age).